# How to save a JSON file in GAE servlet for the request of Android client?

Tags: java, android, json, google-app-engine

At first, Sorry for my poor English.
I write a android app about movie information. In the GAE server,Parsing the movie data everyday. However, To reduce GAE computing flow effectively and access time from the client, I want to take the all parsing results daily to be a Json file. I think all of this reasonable...?
So, How to save a JSON file in my GAE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning on using the Google toolstack you will need to persist the json file to one of persistent file storage services like [Blobstore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/) or [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/).

If it's a small json you could put it into [Google's Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview).

You could always connect to other cloud storage services like [Amazon's S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), but since you're using Google's cloud products it might be easier to stick to them.